# google contacts api not getting all contacts

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, gdata

I have a vb.net application where it retrieves all my contacts.
In stead of doing that for some odd reason the application add my mostly used contacts.
Any help is appreciated.

my code:

```
Dim authSubUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl("http://www.example.com/Welcome.asp", "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full", False, True)

tmpEMailAddress = frmEmp.eMailAddress

'Dim tmpWREmailAddress As String = Mid(frmEmp.eMailAddress, 1, InStr(frmEmp.eMailAddress, "@") - 1) & "@roguevalleydoor.com"
tmpEMailAddress = Mid(frmEmp.eMailAddress, 1, InStr(frmEmp.eMailAddress, "@") - 1) & "@roguevalleydoor.com"

Dim rs As New RequestSettings("GMClient", tmpEMailAddress, frmEmp.NetPW)

' AutoPaging results in automatic paging in order to retrieve all contacts
rs.AutoPaging = True
Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(rs)

Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.GetContacts

ContactsListView.Items.Clear()

If f.Entries.Any = True Then
   Dim lvRow As New ListViewItem

   For Each ea As Contact In f.Entries

       For Each email As EMail In ea.Emails
           If (InStr(email.Address, "@") <> 0) AndAlso (ea.Title.Trim <> "") Then

              lvRow = ContactsListView.Items.Add(ea.Title)
              lvRow.SubItems.Add(email.Address)
           End If
       Next
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

> Note: The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because
>   there's a default limit on the number of results returned. For more
>   information, see the max-results query parameter in Retrieving
>   contacts using query parameters.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts

Comment: @Chandrew what is the maximum limit of `max-results` query parameter